# openerp pyc files not generated

Tags: compilation, odoo, pyc

Good morning to everyone, i am facing this problem:

Sometimes, after making modifications in my .py files, i restarted the server and saw nothing had changed. In fact the .pyc files were not regenerated so i want to know if someone can give me the good procedure to make that happens.

Now what I do is:

step1-add in eclipse params: --update=module_name

step2-click on settings ==> installed modules (the idea is to load the module again)

step3-be sure not to be in debug mode (you can remove debug from the address bar).

Could someone know how to do step 2 without using the web client (browser) i.e a way or a param to add when restarting the server so that the modules will be load again, because i remark that it is in this step that pyc files are regenerated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So reading between the lines, you are working in Eclipse and have changed and the pyc files are not new.

I would:

1. In Eclipse, Project -> Clean and clean your project.
2. Exit Eclipse and see if there is still a debug process lying about and kill it.  These zombie debug processes happen if you terminate the server while it is stopped on a break point (in eclipse juno anyway, not sure about luna).

Either the eclipse builder will generate the pyc because that is part of building a project, or the Python vm will when it encounters the py file, or if a pyc exists it will check the times and ignore the pyc if it is older than the py.  Updating the module may cause OpenERP to load that module and the python vm will generate the pyc but it doesn't matter whether you trigger this by updating the module when the server starts or just when you click on the function that triggers the piece of code.

One last suggestion, check your system time as the python vm is checking the file time stamps.

Comment: not sure to follow:  "it doesn't matter whether you trigger this by updating the module when the server starts or just when you click on the function that triggers the piece of code."

Comment: What I mean is if the pyc file doesn't exist, the python vm will create it when it first hits that bit of code.  It doesn't matter if this happens at server start by updating the module immediately or if you do it later.  The idea is just whenever that first parse happens is when the pyc file is generated.